# Clients of a site are getting SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT (Firefox) and ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT (Chrome)

Tags: centos, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I'm running a site in AlmaLinux 8.8 (Centos) and Apache 2.4.56.
The site has a self-signed certificate.

When I access the site, I get the usual warning due to the self-signed certificate. After accepting that I want to continue, I get the error `SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT` in Firefox and `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT` in Chrome.

On the same server, other sites are working correctly with Cloudflare + Let'Encrypt.

I have no doubts about the SSL configuration on the Apache virtual host file.
I have also carefully checked the certificate.

I ran this debugging tool `openssl s_client -state -debug -showcerts -verify 1 -connect example.com:443`
Below you can find a summary of the output.

I draw attention to the line with `SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure` and another line referring to Cloudflare even though the site is not currently using Cloudflare.

Please, help.

The output of the debugging tool:

```
verify depth is 1
CONNECTED(00000005)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
...
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
...
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
...
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server hello
depth=0 C = XX, L = Default City, O = Default Company Ltd, CN = (...)
verify error:num=18:self-signed certificate
...
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server certificate
...                ...
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server key exchange
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server certificate request
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server done
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client certificate
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client key exchange
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
...
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write finished
...
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in error
0036800901000000:error:0A000410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 40
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = XX, L = Default City, O = Default Company Ltd, CN = (...)
   i:C = XX, L = Default City, O = Default Company Ltd, CN = (...)
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jul 14 11:41:36 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Jul 11 11:41:36 2033 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...

Acceptable client certificate CA names
C = US, O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", OU = Origin Pull, L = San Francisco, ST = California, CN = origin-pull.cloudflare.net
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: 
...
---
SSL handshake has read 1553 bytes and written 456 bytes
Verification error: self-signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 940A6E481407D70D9F5DCFF3DD0760DC10A3A6B4B6F37D602EE8CDB83A736B049DE24DF0C8D4DE57A9E3A403553EC6D6
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1689342131
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self-signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
```

Comment: Do you think this long headline is good? Why do not explain the things in the body?

Comment: Your server is configured to require a client certificate. This is probably a wrong configuration. It is not part of the configuration you show though. You likely have `SSLVerifyClient` configured with the wrong idea of what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the research I performed, several settings on the server and client can cause this error.

After disabling Cloudflare on other sites I found that the error was also happening on those sites even if they had a signed certificate. So the problem was some global Apache configuration.

**I solved the problem by adding this directive `SSLVerifyClient none` to my `httpd.conf` file.**

Apparently, the server was asking the client for a certificate for authentication. Although I did not find the `SSLVerifyClient require` directive in any Apache configuration file. A mystery ;).